# Rails 4 fake ActiveRecord property based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How do I fake a method in a ActiveRecord object to behave like a property if it depends on its associations?

To illustrate, let's say Update belongs_to Item. When I call `Item.purchased_at`, I want it to find the `Update` with `kind: "purchased"` and tell me when it was created:

```
# item.rb

def purchased_at
  self.updates.find_by_kind("purchased").try(:created_at)
end

def purchased_at=(time)
  u = self.updates.find_by_kind("purchased") || self.updates.new(kind: "purchased")
  u.mark_for_destruction unless u.time = time # queue for destruction if time is nil
end
```

My getter method, however, only returns what was already committed. It doesn't show the non-saved values like real ActiveRecord properties do:

```
item = Item.first
item.purchased_at = Time.now
item.save
item.purchased_at = nil
item.purchased_at # returns the current time
```

How should I change my code so `purchased_at` behaves like a real ActiveRecord property?

Comment: Instead of `unless u.time = time` you should use `unless u.time == time`

Comment: No, it's checking whether `time` is nil, not whether the two are equivalent...

Comment: So you should check `unless u.time.blank?`

Comment: It's setting `u.time` to `time` unless `time` is nil, in which case it will `mark_for_destruction`... this is not the problem I think

Comment: If you don't get any update if it's of a purchased kind you want to create it...right?

Comment: Is my assumption right?